# Search function with mutiple params seems to not work everytimes

Tags: laravel

I have a search function with multiple parameters who seems to not work everytimes on each params for exemple i tested the search query with one param "etat_paiement = 0 ",

normaly i should have no results but i still have one but in the database this record have etat_paiement = 1

where i made a mistake ? thanks a lot in advance

here the code :

```
 $query = EngagementOrder::query();

            $filters = [
                'structure_engagement_id' => 'structure_id',
                'saison_id' => 'saison_id',
                'etat_paiement' => 'etat_paiement',
                'bl_comptabilite' => 'bl_comptabilite',
            ];


            foreach ($filters as $key => $column) {
                $query->when($request->{$key}, function ($query, $value) use ($column) {
                    $query->where($column, $value);
                });

            }

            $engagements = $query->paginate(10);
```

in my debug bar i have the query like :

select * from `engagement_order` limit 10 offset 0

but i run the search with the url like :

https://mydomaine/engagements?etat_paiement=0

UPDATE : here my select box :

```
{!! Form::select('etat_paiement', array('1' => 'Facture Réglée' , '0' => 'Facture Non Rélgée') , null , ['class' => 'form-control select2 ', 'placeholder' => 'Selectionnez un type de réglement']) !!}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the laravel's `when` method. When you are passing "0" as the first argument to the `when` function, the below is invoked with the value as "0", which is resolving to be false in this condition: `if ($value)`

```
public function when($value, $callback, $default = null)
{
    if ($value) {
        return $callback($this, $value) ?: $this;
    } elseif ($default) {
        return $default($this, $value) ?: $this;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Instead of using `when`, you can generate the query like this:

```
foreach ($filters as $key => $column) {
        if ($request->has($key)) {
            $query->where($column, $request->{$key});
        }
    }
```

If you want to use `when`, change your code to

```
 foreach ($filters as $key => $column) {
     $query->when($request->has($key), function ($query, $value) use ($column,$key, $request) {
          $query->where($column, $request->$key);
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try `exists` instead of `$request->{$key}` for example:

```
$request->exists($key)
```

In your case `$request->{$key}` is evaluating to false because `etat_paiement=0` has a falsy value. On the other hand, the `exists` will check if the query parameter/`$key` is present regardless of the value.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! still the same problem .. i don't understand

Comment: now the query stay at : select count(*) as aggregate from `engagement_order` where `etat_paiement` = '1' ! with i enter to https://mydomaine/engagements?etat_paiement=0

Comment: To make sure it's working, try `dd($column, $value)` inside the closure.

Comment: ok so when i try with dd($column, $value) if i put etat_paiement = 0 i get true and if i put etat_paiement=1 and get true also ... i don't understand why ! i give you my select box in update of the post

Comment: Yes you should get the value.

Comment: why i get true ? i updated the post with my select box so you can see

Comment: Where u get true?

Comment: i get true in the loop when i dd ($column , $value) is value is true all the time. here the result of the dd : "etat_paiement" true

Comment: @TheAlpha, may I ask you to have a look at a Laravel search related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485513/laravel-search-with-multiple-keywords-against-multiple-columns-with-the-search ?